# Dirac equation: Green's function specified for only one dimension

Tags: field-theory, dirac-equation, spacetime-dimensions, greens-functions, propagator

Normally, the Dirac equation for the Green's function reads:
$$(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - m)S_F(x,y) = \delta^{(4)}(x-y)$$
Is it possible to define a Green's function describing the propagation exclusively in one dimension for this 4-dim problem, i.e. something like
$$(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - m)S_F^{(0)}(x^0,y^0) = \delta(x^0-y^0),$$
where $x^0$ is the first spatial component of the four-vector $x$?

Comment: You can define whatever you want, whether it is useful or not is an entirely different question. It is not clear *how* to concretely answer your question though: your definition does not appear to be useful for anything but, of course, there is no proof, who knows what someone in the future will find useful.

Comment: You can define it, but the solution is not particularly interesting, it's just some Heaviside theta functions. And obviously it's not a Lorentz covariant equation.